# Service Locator works from app but not dynamically-instantiated class

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, service-locator

My app registers a bunch of view models this way:

```
static App()
{
   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
}

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewModelA>();
   ...
}
```

and I'm able to access ViewModelA using:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ViewModelA>()
```

But when the app executes:

```
obj = (MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass);
```

to instantiate a class from a plugin assembly, its constructor executes:

```
public MyClass()
{
   SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewModelB>();
   var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ViewModelB>();
   var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Current;
   var referenceSetUpTabViewModel = serviceLocator.GetInstance<ViewModelB>();

   InitializeComponent();
}
```

ViewModelB is currently just an empty class:

```
public class ViewModelB
{
}
```

The vm variable contains an instance of ViewModelB and serviceLocator variable equals GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc but the serviceLocator.GetInstance line throws exception:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type not found in cache: ViewModelB
```

Since the vm variable was set, it would seem the type was registered successfully, so why can't the service locator get it?

Besides making it easier to switch to a different container, is there some other reason it is recommended to use ServiceLocator? I've isolated my uses of the container to Application_Startup and a ViewModelLocator class, so if I do choose something more heavy-weight than SimpleIoc in the future, it would be pretty trivial to migrate.

Using Microsoft VS2013 Update 4, .NET 4.5.2, MVVM-Light 5.1.1, CommonServiceLocator 1.3.

Comment: What is the accessibility of ViewModelB? Is it public or internal? Perhaps you could post some code on your ViewModelB?

Comment: Why is ViewModelB not registered in the application_startup?

Comment: @Parth Shah: Added class source code

Comment: @RLS: I'm loading the assembly that contains ViewModelB dynamically after application_startup executes.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the the instance of `SimpleIoc` returned by `ServiceLocator.Current` is different from `SimpleIoc.Default`.  Is there a way you can verify if these are indeed the same reference?

Comment: @Mike C: I added SimpleIoc.Default and ServiceLocator.Current to a watch window and did two things: 1) Drilled into the objects and found both have 29 registered view models (all registered by the main app), and  2) Added an object ID, which confirmed both objects are identical.

Comment: @JimC if you copy and paste the code from constructor of MyClass into Application_Startup, are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: @Parth Shah: I copied/pasted the code into App_Startup and it did not throw. Of course, I had to substitute a different class because ViewModelB does not exist in the application (ViewModelB is defined in a plug-in assembly loaded at run-time).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but today the problem I posted about is no longer occurring...the dynamically-loaded assembly can now execute ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(); without throwing an exception. If I can get it back into the failing state, I will add the root cause to this answer for future reference.